# Подсчитать количество слов и указать строки

Tags: linux, bash

Требуется создать файл с количеством встречаемых слов (например, `Word1` и `Word2`) из другого файла и указать строки, в которых эти слова встречаются в следующем формате:

```
Word1: 35 [25, 50, 300, ...]  
Word2: 15 [10, 25, 65, ...]
```

Comment: для bash'а задача уже тяжеловата, тут лучше нечто перло-питоновской группы использовать... ну и конечно не хватает примеров данных и попыток решения т.к. задача крайне смахивает на учебную...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Мы совершенно недавно начала эту тему проходить, так что перл или питон там врядли может быть (мое основное направление пхп). Я уверена, что задачу следует через `grep` реализовать, но что-то не особо получается

Comment: @Sasha указать надо именно строки или номера строк?

Comment: @РашенБеар номера строк

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одной командой этого не сделать, поэтому будем писать bash-скрипт `counter.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Файл с шаблонами поиска, каждое с новой строки
searched="$1"
# Файл, где нужно искать
src="$2"

# Проверяем наличие файла
if [ ! -f "$searched" ]; then
  # Если нет, возвращаем код ошибки + пишем ошибку в stderr
  >&2 echo "File $searched not exists"
  exit 1
fi

# Аналогично
if [ ! -f "$src" ]; then
  >&2 echo "File $src not exists"
  exit 1
fi

# Читаем файл с шаблонами построчно
while read word; do

  # Сохраняем в переменную количество строк с вхождением
  LINES_COUNT=`grep -c "$word" "$src"`

  # Сохраняем в переменную номера строк
  # Команда состоит из трех частей:
  # 1) grep выводит номер строки и найденную подстроку (флаг -n),
  #    флаг `-F` означает искать точное соответствие, а не регулярку
  # 2) cut убирает найденное слово, оставляет только номер строки
  # 3) awk склеивает номера строк
  LINES_NUMBERS=`grep -nF "$word" "$src" | cut -f1 -d: | awk '{printf("%s", NR == 1 ? $0 : ", "$0);}'`

  # Выводим в нужном формате
  echo "$word: $LINES_COUNT [$LINES_NUMBERS]"

done < "$searched"
```

Перед запуском нужно выставить `+x`:

```
chmod +x counter.sh
```

Запускается так:

```
./counter.sh searched.txt src.txt
```

- `searched.txt` - файл со словами для поиска, нельзя оставлять пустую строку в конце, иначе будет куча совпадений по этой пустой подстроке
- `src.txt` - файл, где искать

PS.

Если не нужен именно такой формат, можно использовать `grep -onf searched.txt src.txt`

Comment: Ого! А почему так сложно? `grep -nwo -F $word $file` по идее должен выдать всю необходимую информацию. Переформатировать можно `sed`. И ещё, зачем это творчество с *procfs*? `>&2` не работает?

Comment: @0andriy, у меня в PS стоит такой вариант поиска. А по условию, нужно выдавать в том формате, что по учебному заданию у ТС

Comment: @0andriy, `это творчество с procfs` - ошибки ведь надо выводить в stderr?

Comment: Так `>&2` не работает что ли?

Comment: @0andriy, поправил